# return record through LINQ statement

Tags: asp.net, linq

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
Select_Utilities SelectedUtility = (from su in db.Select_Utilities
                                    where su.id == SelectUtilityId
                                    && su.Worksite_Id == WorksiteId
                                     && su.Utility_Company.id == UtilityCompanyId
                                     select su).FirstOrDefault();
```

then I wanted to say SelectedUtility.comment = "whatever the comment may be";

BUT getting ERROR: cannot implicity convert type 'Select_Utility' to 'Select_Utilities'

with 'FirstOrDefault' in statement....any advice?

Thanks

Comment: yeah thanks...how come it can choose both...creates the plural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change result type to `Select_Utility`

```
Select_Utility SelectedUtility =  // here
   (from su in db.Select_Utilities
    where su.id == SelectUtilityId && 
          su.Worksite_Id == WorksiteId && 
          su.Utility_Company.id == UtilityCompanyId
    select su).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus agree :) with linq I almost always use `var` because results are often projected to anonymous types

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `Select_Utilities` is the name of your Entity table which ruturns a collection of `Select_Utility` objects.  Try:

```
Select_Utility selectedUtility = (from su in db.Select_Utilities
                                  where su.id == SelectUtilityId
                                     && su.Worksite_Id == WorksiteId
                                     && su.Utility_Company.id == UtilityCompanyId
                                  select su).FirstOrDefault();
```